# react d3 : error Cannot read property 'string' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-d3

In reactd3,  I get this error when I try to import:

```
var PieTooltip = require('react-d3-tooltip').PieTooltip;
```

How do I fix it?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined

  79 |   scaleExtent: [1, 10]
  80 | }, _commonProps2.default);
  81 | ChartSvg.propTypes = {
> 82 |   id: _react.PropTypes.string,
```

[image: full error formatted]

Answer (score 0):

Since version 15.5, PropTypes are moved to the package "prop-types" (as explained on https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

The last release of react-d3-core is based on React v0.14.7, so PropTypes were included in React at this time. If your app is using a more recent version of React, PropTypes cannot be taken directly from React.

This issue must be solved on the lib react-d3-core, but it seems to be no longer maintained. Either you correct the lib yourself, or you may try to include it manually (this might be a bit more complicated).